# mergesort algorithm Python

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I am learning algorithms on Python.  I have problem with understanding  mergesort. 
I don't understand  how we store all these  finite sorted arrays with number of elements 1 after recursion.  We have left  and right arrays with 1 element  after recursion .  Where we store  these many arrays .

```
def copymergesort(A):
    """
    Merge of A and return  a new collection
    """
    if len(A) < 2:
        return A
    mid =  len(A)/2
    left  = copymergesort(A[:mid])
    right  = copymergesort(A[mid:])

    i = j = 0
    B = []

    while len(B) < len(A):
        if j >= len(right) or (i < mid and left[i] < right [j]):
            B.append(left[i])
            i +=1
        elif  j < len(right):
            B.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    return B
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because general questions about algorithms (and not problems with specific implementations) [are likely to find a better audience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange) at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @jedwards Well this is about a specific implementation, isn't it?

Comment: @OP The subarrays aren't explicitly stored in local variables, they're "stored" in the call stack, in that each recursive call has a scope, and the `A` parameter in this scope is one of the subarrays from the previous recursive call.

Comment: @Asad, no.  The question *has* an implementation, but it's not *about* the implementation.  More specifically, it's not about *problems with* with implementation.  The actual question has little to nothing to do with the implementation that was pasted below it.  OP wants to (or needs to) know how mergesort works *first*, then they can focus on understanding an implementation.  And that "how an algorithm works" is better suited for programmers.se, imho.

Answer (score 1):

You have two expressions in your recursive call, `A[:mid]` and `A[mid:]`. Each of these is a *slice*, which makes a copy of some portion of the list. This is part of the storage you're looking for, it is in these temporary variables which are created for each call and released when the call returns.

You also create a list `B` which is built from scratch, which contains each element that is being merged. This list is returned to the caller, and is released when the caller returns.